# Can ransomware or viruses effect or infect a Linux formatted drive connected to a Windows machine and accessed through a VM?

Tags: windows, vmware

I have a Linux formatted external drive. I usually use it on my Linux box but occasionally I plug it into my Windows machine...

Can a Windows ransomware or another malicious Windows software take over my external drive? Am I at risk?

The two infections I've gotten don't seem to be advanced enough for that but I know things are changing all the time...

Comment: Read here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/566385/about-virtual-machine-windows7-and-a-secure-workflow.

Theoretically it is possible but fairly unlikely.

Comment: Is the drive mounted in windows as read only?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that A virus could transfer over from the external hard drive to your Linux.  However that would mean that the virus works for both Windows and Ubuntu/Linux.  Most of the time all viruses are made for Windows so if your external hard drive was affected and wasn't made for Linux than you are safe.  However if this was done by someone who wants **your** computer infected personally, than there is about nothing that you can do because they could just make another virus.